# yearvalue option is not visible in the jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datepicker

How we can display the date in `dd-mm-yyyy` format using jquery datepicker, I tried with the below code, however, the year option is not visible in the datepicker.

```
jQuery("#formComp1_date").datepicker({    
       minDate: new Date(1, 1, 1900), 

   maxDate: new Date(dayValue, monthValue, yearValue),
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy' ,
        changeMonth: true,

     changeYear: true,
     yearRange:"-90:+0"

 });
```

Thanks,
Balaji.

Comment: The `dateFormat` option is how the date is show in the textbox - it's not shown in the date picker.  Also, you only need `dd-mm-yy`.  It automatically shows a 4-figure year number.  Using `dd-mm-yyyy` will show the current year as 20122012.

Comment: Hi Kmatyaszek,thanks for your reply,so only change that I need to make is change the dateFormat to dd-mm-yy, I will change that and let you know, thanks again

Comment: Thanks Archer,it is fine now after changing the format to dd-mm-yy